Azure functions add custom environment variable during publish
I currently have access to an environment variable in the bash shell where I publish an Azure Function, and I would like to have access to the same environment variable inside of my function app.
My pipeline currently looks something like this:
az login --service-principal -u $USRN -p $PASSW --tenant $TENANT
func azure functionapp publish $FUNCTION_APP_NAME --python

Is is possible to specify some environment variables (I.e CONNECTION_URL=example.com) during function publish?
I have seen actions such as --publish-local-settings, --publish-settings-only, and --overwrite-settings, but I don't think they can help with one specific environment variable. Thank you for any help!

Hi @SteinnHauserMagnússon, Have you got a chance to check my update below? When using the --publish-local-settings option to publish our project files, values in the ConnectionStrings section are never published. Hope it can resolve your concerns. Thx.

Update
According to this document on how to work with app settings locally,

By default, local settings aren't migrated automatically when the project is published to Azure. Use the --publish-local-settings option when you publish your project files to make sure these settings are added to the function app in Azure. Values in the ConnectionStrings section are never published.

The discussions in this thread also suggested storing connection strings in app settings of the published app. If you would prefer using Azure Functions Core Tools for deployment, you may consider specifying your connection strings inside Values nodes of the local.settings.json.
local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "CONNECTION_URL": "example_CONNECTION_URL_BY_FUNC.com"
  }
}

pipeline.yml
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: BuildAndDeploy
  jobs:
  - job: BuildAndDeployWithFunc
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: "Set Python version to 3.11"
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.11'
        architecture: 'x64'
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
        fi
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          echo "================1. Install Azure Functions Core Tools on Ubuntu MS-hosted agent================"
          sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools-4
          func --version
          echo "================2. Deploy Azure Function App with Azure Functions Core Tools================"
          func azure functionapp publish $(AzureFunctionApp) --python --publish-local-settings --overwrite-settings true
      displayName: Deploy function app with Azure Functions Core Tools


However, we should never store local.settings.json in a remote repository,  because it may contain secrets such as connection strings. Besides, local.settings.json is usually added in the .gitignore file by default, which prevent local.settings.json from being pushed to the remote repo. For this, we may opt to use this Azure CLI command to update app settings.
pipeline.yml
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: BuildAndDeploy
  jobs:
  - job: BuildAndDeployWithFunc
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: "Set Python version to 3.11"
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.11'
        architecture: 'x64'
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
        fi
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          echo "================1. Install Azure Functions Core Tools on Ubuntu MS-hosted agent================"
          sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools-4
          func --version
          echo "================2. Update Azure Function App Settings with Azure CLI================"
          az functionapp config appsettings set --name $(AzureFunctionApp) --resource-group rg-azfunctionapp-linux --settings CONNECTION_URL="example_CONNECTION_URL_BY_AZCLI.com"
          echo "================3. Deploy Azure Function App with Azure Functions Core Tools================"
          func azure functionapp publish $(AzureFunctionApp) --python
      displayName: Deploy function app with Azure Functions Core Tools




If your requirement is to configure app settings of the Azure Function App, you may test to use the Azure DevOps pipeline task AzureFunctionApp@2, which enables us to set environment variables during app deployment.
Instead of authenticating against user principal and their password like your az login command, this task uses Azure Resource Manager service connection for authentication, whose underlying principal is an app registration usually assigned with subscription/resource group contributor role. Therefore, it also helps avoid the risk of password leakage or obstacle by user MFA.
Here is a sample YAML pipeline for your reference.
variables:
  ARMSvcCnn: TheARMSvcCnnName
  AzureFunctionApp: TheFunctionAppName

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: BuildJob
    steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: "Set Python version to 3.9"
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.9'
        architecture: 'x64'
    - bash: |
        if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
        then
            dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
        fi
        pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" -r ./requirements.txt
    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: "Archive files"
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveFile: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
        artifactName: 'drop'

- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeploymentJob
    environment: AzureFunctionAppPython
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
            inputs:
              connectedServiceNameARM: '$(ARMSvcCnn)'
              appType: 'functionAppLinux'
              appName: '$(AzureFunctionApp)'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/build$(Build.BuildId).zip'
              appSettings: '-TestEnvVar $(Build.BuildId) -CONNECTION_URL example$(Build.BuildId).com'
              deploymentMethod: 'auto'





Wow thank you. +1. I think this would require quite a lot of restructuring in my pipelines unfortunately. Its currently still seeming like func azure functionapp publish has no option for this though

Hi @SteinnHauserMagnússon, Thanks for your clarification. I have shared more findings in the updated answer. Hope it can help resolve your concerns. Thx.

Besides, here is the document for your reference to help understand the usage of func azure functionapp publish and its options

Perfect! Thank you for the edits after the clarification :)
